# Spring cloud gateway test

Tags: integration-testing, spring-cloud-gateway

I have implemented simple gateway with spring cloud gateway.
It redirects requests from {host-gateway}/gateway/{uri} to {routes.uri}/{uri}, if uri starts from service name from list routes.services

```
@Configuration
public class DefaultRoutesConfig {

    @Value("#{'${routes.services}'.split(',')}")
    private List<String> services;

    @Value("${routes.uri}")
    private String uri;

    @Bean
    public RouteLocator routes(RouteLocatorBuilder builder) {
        RouteLocatorBuilder.Builder routesBuilder = builder.routes();
        for (String id : services) {
            routesBuilder.route(id, p -> p
                    .path("/gateway/" + id +"/**")
                    .filters(f -> f.stripPrefix(1))
                    .uri(uri)
            );
        }
        return routesBuilder.build();
    }
}
```

How to write integration test for this logic?

Comment: Were you able to solve this please?